# infinite loop of Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I use an SQLite database in an application, I was trying to add a function that gets some data from the database in a form of a hashmap

```
 public HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<OrderCustomer>> getOrderCustomers (){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ORDER_CUSTOMER + " ;";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<OrderCustomer>> result = new HashMap<>();

        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            int fkOrder = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(OC_FK_ORDER));
            int fkCustomer = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(OC_FK_CUSTOMER));
            double cost = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(OC_COST));

            OrderCustomer orderCustomer = new OrderCustomer(fkOrder, fkCustomer);
            orderCustomer.setCost(cost);

            ArrayList<OrderCustomer> orderCustomers = new ArrayList<>();

            if(result.containsKey(fkOrder)){
                orderCustomers = result.get(fkOrder);
                result.remove(fkOrder);
            }
            orderCustomers.add(orderCustomer);
            result.put(fkOrder, orderCustomers);
    }
        db.close();
        cursor.close();

        return result;
}
```

but since I added this function the app gives me an infinite loop of the following:

```
Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 133964(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 29MB/31MB, paused 34.098ms total 149.711ms
```

and does not start, and sometimes it crashes with OutOfMemoryError pointing to that function.
What's wrong in the function that causes that error?.
PS: the app works fine once after the first installation, this may help.
Please ask if you any more info.

Comment: `while (! cursor.isAfterLast())` is the recipe for an endless loop, when not moving the cursor forward. this condition might even miss the last one record, because it breaks 1 iteration too soon.

Comment: I missed up again, but thank you that fixed the problem, but would you please explain why it breaks 1 iteration too soon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are never **moving** past the first row so the cursor will never be **after the last row** and hence the infinite loop. This could be fixed by adding `cursor.moveToNext();` before the next iteration of the loop.

However, I'd suggest using the simpler

```
while(cursor.moveToNext) {
    ....... 
}
```

Instead of using (see comment for fix)

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){

    cursor.moveToNext(); // <<<<<<<<<< what was omitted
}
```

- The above would result in a failure if there were no rows extracted as the moveToFirst isn't checked to see if it was successful.

As such I'd suggest changing you code to be :-

```
public HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<OrderCustomer>> getOrderCustomers (){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ORDER_CUSTOMER + " ;";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<OrderCustomer>> result = new HashMap<>();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        int fkOrder = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(OC_FK_ORDER));
        int fkCustomer = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(OC_FK_CUSTOMER));
        double cost = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(OC_COST));

        OrderCustomer orderCustomer = new OrderCustomer(fkOrder, fkCustomer);
        orderCustomer.setCost(cost);

        ArrayList<OrderCustomer> orderCustomers = new ArrayList<>();

        if(result.containsKey(fkOrder)){
            orderCustomers = result.get(fkOrder);
            result.remove(fkOrder);
        }
        orderCustomers.add(orderCustomer);
        result.put(fkOrder, orderCustomers);
    }     
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return result;
}
```

- Notes

  - `getReadableDatabase` will in most situations get a writable database
  - `cursor.moveToFirst()` has been removed (moveToNext will move to the first row when the cursor is at the position of before the first row (i.e. -1)).
  - The cursor should be closed before the database is closed

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help Mike I'll apply your changes.